# Backbone cannot sort by/access nested model attribute

Tags: sorting, backbone.js

I'm not sure why, but I can't sort my collection by a nested attribute in my collection. Below is a screenshot of the collection. I can successfully sort by an attribute like "title" as seen below, but not by a nested attribute like ratings.critics_rating or ratings.audience_score. When I try to log out a or b for the nested attributes, I get "undefined".

This works:

```
  comparator: (a, b) ->
    log 'comparing'
    a = a.get('title') ## works
    b = b.get('title') ## works
    return 0 if a is b
    if a > b then 1 else -1
```

This doesn't

```
  comparator: (a, b) ->
    log 'comparing'
    a = a.get('ratings.critics_rating') ## doesnt work
    b = b.get('ratings.critics_rating') ## doesnt work
    ...
```

[image: Collection Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Model.get`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get) accesses the attributes on the model but doesn't try to access nested attributes : `a.get('ratings.critics_rating')` is equivalent to `a.attributes['ratings.critics_rating']` and that's not what you want.

Try `a.get('ratings').critics_rating` instead,

```
comparator: (a, b) ->
    log 'comparing'
    a = a.get('ratings').critics_rating
    b = b.get('ratings').critics_rating
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/4Lzx1vw5/

Comment: The documentation for this function should include a more advanced example like this.